# Sitecore, render Item in code with personalization in mvc

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

My terminology might be slightly off as I am new to Sitecore mvc.  I am trying to hardcode a view rendering with a hard coded datasource (I have to do it this way for other requirements)  This view rendering has placeholders that are dynamically set and then personalized.

How can I trigger the ViewRendering on an item?

I've tried ItemRendering, but it doesn't seem to be picking up the stuff set up in the PageEditor.

*** To be clear, the helpful posts below have the rendering working, but we do not seem to be getting the personalized datasources. ***

Comment: I leaning toward removing the static view, moving the custom controller rules into the personalization engine, and then setting it all up in the page editor using the personalization engine.

Answer (score 4):

I *believe* this is what you're after:

```csharp
Item item = /* think you already have this */;

// Setup
var rendering = new Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering {
  RenderingType = "Item",
  Renderer = new Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ItemRenderer.ItemRenderer {
    Item = item
  }
};
rendering["DataSource"] = item.ID.ToString();

// Execution
var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
var args = new Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering(rendering, writer);
Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline("mvc.renderRendering", args);

// Your result:
var html = writer.ToString();
```

Comment: that gets the control, but not my personalization rules.  Maybe my problem is in the actual content setup?  How do you set up pesonalization rules on an ItemRendering?

Comment: The only thing I could think to do would pass off the layout details (since they define what goes in what placeholder at what time), but that would need to be in the context of a specific page (since they can obviously vary by page). At the item level, however, you're probably pretty limited (unless you customized the template to add a Rules field (then execute against that rules context before rendering).) Know what I mean?

Comment: I think I read a post about that from sitecore, seems a little complex for the end user.  Do you know of a way to execute and add the result of another page to the current page?  UrlRenderer works kind of like this, but you lose the original user information.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). May I ask what the initial intent is and take it from there?

Comment: The requirement we are trying to solve is basically trying to personalize child views of our header such as a promotion.  The problem that makes it a little trickier is that we have a datasource rules in the controller of the header forcing us to use a ViewRendering / ItemRendering.  To set up rules, I added a hollow layout to the item, allowing us to set the rules.  I've tried quite a few things other than this, but really just kind of thrashing around

Comment: I get an error `Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering is a namespace but is used like a type`. Please fix your code.

Comment: I tried this code but when I run the code `html` is empty. Any idea why?

Comment: I am getting an error like this Attempt to retrieve context object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext' from empty stack.

Sitecore.Mvc

Answer (score 1):

You can statically bind a View Rendering using the `Rendering()` method of the Sitecore HTML Helper. This also works for Controller Renderings using the same method.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("<rendering item id>")
```

This method accepts an anonymous object for passing in parameters, such as the Datasource and caching options.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("<rendering item id>", new { DataSource = "<datasource item id>", Cacheable = true, Cache_VaryByData = true })
```

In your view rendering, I am assuming you have a placeholder defined along with the appropriate placeholder settings in Sitecore (If not, feel free to comment with more detail and I will update my answer).

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("my-placeholder")
```

In this case, "my-placeholder" will be handled like any other placeholder, so you will be able to add and personalize components within it from the Page Editor.

Comment: Actually Derek, perhaps I am asking the wrong questions.  I want to render an Item as if it was a fresh html request.  Using the layout and personalization rules set on that item.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your initial question. You are attempting to do this programmatically, right? Do you want the full/complete HTML for the item, or are you only concerned with a specific rendering?

Comment: I guess either would work.  Right now I have a layout assigned to the item which has what I need.  I'd be glad to use a rendering, but it just isn't grabbing the layout details and personalization rules.